# Create a Thumbnail Image Companion for a MultiScaleimage Control

Tags: .net, thumbnails, multiscaleimage

I have an application that uses a MultiScaleImage control and I would like to add a thumnbnail window with the unzoomed image and a rectangle outline indicating the portion being viewed in the MultiScaleImage control. I don't have thumbnails for the images but want to create them at runtime.

1) is there a way to get a copy of the unzoomed image from the MultiScaleImage control to put into an Image control or do I have to just use another MultiScaleImage control with the same Source.

2) Any hints or examples would be appreciated.

David

Answer (score 0):

Use the WriteableBitmap class. If multiscaleImage is a MultiscaleImage control and thumbnail is an Image control, then this code will capture the image from the former and display it in the latter.

```
WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(multiScaleImage, null);
Thumbnail.Source = bitmap;
```

David

Comment: The problem with this is that the bitmap is updated whenever the MultiScaleImage control is updated. What I really want is a snapshot of the contents of the MultiScaleImage control for the thumbnail, which won't change wne panning or zooming about in the MultiScaleImage control.

Answer (score 0):

Please see Jeff Prosise's blog post on this, use the last function he suggests:

http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/12/17/silverlight-s-big-image-problem-and-what-you-can-do-about-it.aspx

you could adapt it appropriately (has the added benefit that it won't need to render the whole huge image in memory, it should render it directly scaled so MultiScaleImage would use the correct zoom level data for that small scale)

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, references tend to get stale over time. Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.